# How to use the reference type efficiently to access a document in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So basically what I am trying is, access a document throught a reference attribut that is written in an other document like this:

[Screen of the collection and the document that contains the references in an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glU6N.png)

Here is the javascript function with which I would like to access the document. In this example I just return the reference attribut to see what it contains:

```js
exports.importProducts = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
   
   const res = { success: false, error: "", docrefs: []};
   const groceryListID = "groceryList1";
   try {
       const groceryListDoc = await admin
           .firestore()
           .collection("GroceryList")
           .doc(groceryListID.toString())
           .get();
       if (!groceryListDoc.exists) {
           res.error =
               "Grocery list could not be found";
           response.send(res);
           // return res;
       }
       else {
           const docref = groceryListDoc.data().docReferences;
           res.success = true;
           res.docrefs = docref[0];
           response.send(res);
       }
   }
   catch (e) {
       res.error = "Error while reading the Grocery List document : " + e;
       response.send(res);
       //return res;
   }
});
```

Here is the result I get when im reading the reference attribut:

[Result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8Nq.png)

Result in text format: {"success":true,"error":"","docrefs":{"_firestore":{"projectId":""},"_path":{"segments":["Products","p1"]},"_converter":{}}}

I know that I could parse the array elements of the "segments" to get the path and access to the document but is there a better way manage that? Maybe thanks a DocumentReference object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that the SDK gives you back for a `DocumentReference` field type in the database is actually a `DocumentReference` object from the SDK too. So you can just call `get()` on the value you get, to get a snapshot of the references document data.